# How to clear window variables when using turbolinks

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks-5

Using ruby on rails, I have code that is triggered with the following coffee script;

````
$ = jQuery
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  if window.progress?
    // execute code on a div with an id of ```target```
````

On pages where the code is meant to trigger, I have a div with an id of `target` and a script tag which loads the `progress` parameter
e.g.

```
<%= javascript_tag id: "window_vars" do %>
  window.progress = <%= raw graph.data.to_json %>
<% end -%>
```

If there is no turbolinks, then this works fine, the code triggers on the pages where it is meant to and does not trigger on the other pages. However, if I enable turbolinks 5.0.1 and I visit a page where the code is not meant trigger, then to a page where the code does trigger, and then back to the page where the code is not meant to trigger, the code triggers on the final page with an exception. It seems that turbolinks is not clearing the window.progress variable between page loads.

How do I make sure that the window variables loaded via a script are cleared between pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this same issue today doing something similar. What I've surmised is that global variables persist between turbolinks visits. This actually makes sense since the page isn't reloaded; the content is just overwritten. My solution was to destroy the data before turbolinks renders a new page.

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:before-render', () => {
  delete window.progress;
})
```

Note that the `delete` method does not work with javascript variables declared with `var`, but does work for attributes assigned to `window` as in my case. If using `var`, you'll want to do `var progress = null`;

You have [a lot of options](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#full-list-of-events) for where to do this in the lifecycle of a request. I chose before-render to ensure data is only 'destroyed' if the request was successful.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to not rely on the window.progress to detect if the graph is present, rather use the id e.g.

```
if $('#target').length > 0
```